# Layer Stacking landsat 5 surface reflectance high level data

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, landsat-5

I downloaded the surface reflectance landsat 5 scenes but when I layer stacked them my image was not how I imagined. I manually used atcor on normal scenes and it looks nothing like the scenes I layer stacked. Is there a certain order the tiffs have to be stacked for my image to come out correct?

I recently deleted the images and am going to try to use atcor myself. Do I need to download a calibration file for Landsat 5TM or can I use the default tm_essen.cal?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Could you please provide more details on what your expected output looks like.  A screenshot of your current (unusual) results would be helpful too.

Comment: jkamsu I have removed the other account as you had two accounts from the same ip address please only use one account for GIS SE, thanks.

Comment: @jkamsu If you are not able to access your original account then I think you should [contact us](http://gis.stackexchange.com/contact) to try and sort out anything that may be causing you problems accessing this site.